# Failed to resolve component: Label in Vue js

Tags: vuejs3

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZISUt.png)
I am new at vue js.Currently i am learning how make form in vue js but i am getting above error in console.I am putting my code below.

I've been scouring the internet and documentation for answers for hours now, and nothing I find seems to work.

Beacuse of this error i cannot even print the data in console that i am getting from this form

```
<form v-on:submit="submitform">
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" v-model="formvalues.name1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="profile">Profile Summary</label>
      <textarea id="profile" v-model="formvalues.profilesummery"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
      <Label for="country">Country</Label>
      <select id="country" v-model="formvalues.country">
        <option value="">Select a Country</option>
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="dubai">Dubai</option>
        <option value="uk">UK</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      <Label for="jib-location">Job Locations</Label>
      <select id="jib-location" multiple v-model="formvalues.jobLocation">
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="dubai">Dubai</option>
        <option value="uk">UK</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="remortwork" true-value="yes" false-value="no" v-model="formvalues.remotework">
      <label for="remortwork">Open for remort work?</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="">Skill Set</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="html" value="html" v-model="formvalues.skillset">
      <label for="html">HTML</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="css" value="css" v-model="formvalues.skillset">
      <label for="css">CSS</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="javascript" value="javascript" v-model="formvalues.skillset">
      <label for="javascript">Javascript</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="">Years of Experience</label>
      <input type="radio" value="0-2" id="0-2" v-model="formvalues.yearsofexprience">
      <label for="0-2" >0-2</label>
      <input type="radio" value="3-5" id="3-5" v-model="formvalues.yearsofexprience">
      <label for="0-2" >3-5</label>
      <input type="radio" value="6-10" id="6-10" v-model="formvalues.yearsofexprience">
      <label for="0-2" >6-10</label>
      <input type="radio" value="10+" id="10+" v-model="formvalues.yearsofexprience">
      <label for="0-2" >10+</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Here is js for above code

```
formvalues: {
        name1: '',
        profilesummery: '',
        country: '',
        jobLocation: [],
        remotework: "no",
        skillset:[],
        yearsofexprience:[]
      }
```

Can anyone give me solution for this error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a classic case of case-sensitive code. Vue is complaining that you haven't defined a component named `<Label>` and I'm assuming its just a mistake from your end where it should have been `<label>` instead.

update `<Label>` to `<label>`, and it should resolve your issue.

FYI the following lines need to change :

```
<Label for="country">Country</Label>
```

and

```
<Label for="jib-location">Job Locations</Label>
```

Simply update them like below to ensure the L in label isn't capitalized.

```
<label for="jib-location">Job Locations</label>
<label for="country">Country</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but even after changing 'label' to 'Label' I still get an error

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Or is it a different error this time?

Comment: Okay I just re-read your comment now. You have changed it wrong. You need to change Label to label, not the other way around. Make sure your label tags do NOT have a capital L.

Comment: I have changed Label to label. but still I am getting the same error